# neural network that reconfigures connections not just weights using evolution

Tags: networking

I tried to ask this question on stack exchange but i don't have any reputation and it wouldn't let me enter any tags.

Where can i find information about neural networks which not only get trained by changing the weights, but modifying the connections between the neurones? I have a c++ neural network i have been building which is object orientated and can do this and I am interested in training it using the principles of evolution like i have to change the weights, except this time also so it actually modifies the mesh of connections between neurones.

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm called NEAT (Neural Evolution of Augmenting Topologies). I think it does exactly what you are looking for. Look it up and you will find some papers that explain how it works. I haven't found any help on how to implement it properly but by reading the paper you should get a good idea on how you could implement a solution for your problem.